# Convert jsxbin to jsx

Tags: javascript

I converted jsx to jsxbin file with visual studio codes, but it automatically deleted my jsx file. Is there option to return original file?
I tried to download converter from git but I am not sure how to use that on Mac?
Please help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.